# Как проверить значение в строке до точки?

Tags: php, массивы, строки

Имеются строки в массиве

```
login.remember = ‘1’

login.name = ‘userName’

login.password = ‘password’
```

Как проверить если встречается значение до точки с одинаковой частью то нужно создать массив где login станет ключем нового массива вот такого вида

```
login   =>  array(remember=>1,
        name=username,
        password=password)
```

Comment: Алгоритм нужен или готовое решение? :)

Comment: @nathara или готовое или с пиощью чего получем результат т.е с чем работать

Comment: @Анатолийй, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Для начала опишите, эти строки откуда вы берете, из файла, из переменной, из воздуха...? Как вы пытались их разделять? Что при этом у вас не получается. т.к. помочь тут прост скажем воспользовавшись функцией  explode в цикле вы можете получить такие массивы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот примерное решение:
Я бы еще добавил всякие там проверки $matches и т.п

```
$lines = array("login.remember = '1'","login.name = 'userName'","login.password = 'password'");
$new_array = array();
$pattern = "/([^\.]+)\.([^\=]+)\s?=\s?'([^']+)'/";
foreach($lines as $line)
{
    preg_match($pattern,$line,$matches);
    $key     = $matches[1];
    $sub_key = $matches[2];
    $value   = $matches[3];

    if (!isset($new_array[$key])
    {
        $new_array[$key] = array();
    }
    $new_array[$key][$sub_key] = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array();
function add1($val)
{
   $ex = explode('.',$val,2);
   $key1 = $ex[0];
   $val1 = $ex[1];
   $ex2 = explode('=',$val1,2);
   $key2 = $ex2[0];
   $val2 = $ex2[1];

   $arr[$key1][$key2] = $val2;
}
add1("login.remember = ‘1’");
add1("login.name = ‘userName’");
add1("login.password = ‘password’");
```

**p.s.** Не тестил, но должно работать :)

Comment: Забыли про кавычки обратные trim( $val2,"‘ ");

Comment: @binliz ну да ) но я хотел дать примерный код, как можно сделать )

Answer (score 0):

На основе этой вялотекущей серии вопросов, связанных с обработкой этих ваших конфигов я запилил для этих целей [класс для парсинга конфигов](http://www.lotoflot.com/php-cfg/).

Пользоваться вот как:

```
$s = <<<EOD
login.remember = ‘1’
login.name = ‘userName’
login.password = ‘password’
EOD;

$parser_cfg = array(
    'quote-open' => '‘',    // необычная открывающая кавычка
    'quote-close' => '’',   // необычная закрывающая кавычка
    );

$cfg = new cfg($s, $parser_cfg);

$remember = $cfg['login.remember'];

// или так:
$remember = $cfg['login']['remember'];

// или если нужно изменить параметр:
$cfg['login.remember'] = 0;
```

Можно прямо в описании класса настроить кавычки, чтобы не приходилось постоянно передавать настройки парсера в конструктор.